# Save location of multiple labels to SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello this is code which `creates multiple labels` to exact position that is saved in SQL DB. Now I'm wondering how it will be possible to save location of each label (because I'm able to move them like `Drag and drop`). I was wondering how should the code look like because when I create a label during runtime it is without name, isn't it? I'm not sure how it should be assigned.

Would anyone help me solve this out please?

This is the code for load:

```
private void createLabelFromSql()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM [schema] WHERE id=@id";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idSch);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader read= com.ExecuteReader();

                while (read.Read())
                {
                    mouseX = Int32.read(read["x"].ToString());
                    mouseY = Int32.read(read["y"].ToString());
                    createLabelCmd();

                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
            }
            finally { conn.Close(); }

        }
    private void createLabelCmd()
        {

                        newLabel = new Label();
                        newLabel.Location = new Point(mouseY, mouseX);
                        newLabel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseMove);
                        newLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseDown);
                        panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);

        }
```

I thought that it might be somehow like this but not sure how to handle the name thing:

```
            string query = "UPDATE [schema] SET x=@x, y=@y WHERE id=@id";
      SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x",label1.Location.X);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", label1.Location.Y);

      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way:

```
 private void createLabelFromSql()
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [schema] WHERE id=@id";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, spojeni);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idSch);
            spojeni.Open();
            SqlDataReader precti = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (precti.Read())
            {
                createLabelCmd((int)precti["x"], (int)precti["y"]);
            }
            spojeni.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
        finally { spojeni.Close(); }
    }

    private void createLabelCmd(int x, int y)
    {
        var newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Location = new Point(y, x);
        newLabel.Font = new Font(newLabel.Font.FontFamily.Name, 9, FontStyle.Bold);
        newLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        newLabel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseMove);
        newLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyControl_MouseDown);
        panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    }

    private void SaveAllLabels()
    {
        spojeni.Open();

        //delete all data
        SqlCommand delCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM  [schema] WHERE id=@id", spojeni);
        delCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idSch);
        delCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //create new data for current state
        string query = "INSERT INTO [schema] VALUES (@x, @y, @id)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, spojeni);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@y", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idSch);

        foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (item is Label)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@x"].Value = item.Location.X;
                cmd.Parameters["@y"].Value = item.Location.Y;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        spojeni.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give each `label` a name?

**Eidt**:
Assuming `id` is the `Primary Key` of the table you can get it via:

```
private void createLabelFromSql()
{
....
....
 while (read.Read())
 {
     mouseX = Int32.read(read["x"].ToString());
     mouseY = Int32.read(read["y"].ToString());
     createLabelCmd(Int32.Parse(read["id"].ToString())); // you can extract the id here
 }
 conn.Close();
}
```

And alter saving method as:

```
 string query = "UPDATE [schema] SET x=@x, y=@y WHERE id=@id";
 SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand(query, conn);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x",label1.Location.X);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", label1.Location.Y);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(label1.Name.Replace("lbl","")));
....
```

**End of Edit ,**

```
private void createLabelCmd(int id)
{
    newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Name = "lbl" + id.ToString();
    newLabel.Location = new Point(mouseY, mouseX);
.....
.....
}
```

Comment: giving the name to each lbl might be useful, I might then assign it in for loop maybe.

Comment: @Marek I believ assigning the name is the solution. However, I couldn't get your idea. Do you have any problem using Name property?

Comment: I haven't down-vote. Is there any way to solve this please? `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", (label+i).Location.X);` ? It is in for loop.

Comment: I have no problem with that but I didn't knew how can I bind the newly added name to SqlCommand, thanks for your time.